# How to realize these transfer functions through op-amp circuit?

Tags: transfer-function

How to synthesize the follwing tansfer function using analog circuit:
$$\frac{(1+sT_1)(1-sT_2)}{as^2+bs+c}$$

Comment: More explain!!!

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please tell us what you have tried to answer this question yourself, and where you are getting stuck. If this is a homework problem, please say so.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** - there was a basic error in this answer - I missed the negative term in the numerator - the numerator I should have read is \$(1+sT_1)(1-sT_2)\$ but Alfred Centauri has come to the rescue with a two op-amp scheme that achieves this part - see his answer for the second term in the numerator and my answer for the remainder.

The transfer function you have is this: -

H = \$\dfrac{(1+sT_1)(1+sT_2)}{as^2+bs+c}\$ (apart from the error as mentioned above)

And this can be realized with a cascade of three op-amp circuits. The denominator has the form of a 2nd order low pass filter and using a sallen key topology this can be realized: -

[image]

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sallen%E2%80%93Key_topology) stage covers the denominator and also introduces an element in the numerator, \$\omega_0^2\$ and this is a constant. To produce 1+s\$T_n\$ requires a differentiator circuit similar to this: -

[image]

If R1 and R2 are equal this becomes \$1+sR_2\$

Two of these circuits need to be cascaded to get the full numerator. These are then cascaded with the sallen key stage (above) and the transfer function will be: -

H = \$\dfrac{\omega_0^2(1+sCR_a)(1+sCR_b)}{s^2+s2\zeta\omega_0+\omega_0^2}\$

I think this is near enough to the original transfer function to show how it might be implemented in an analogue circuit using op-amps. Don't forget to look at Alfred's answer for the erroneous term I included.

Comment: Thanks a lot ...but how to synthesize RHP zero is the difficulty i am facing...is it possible to synthesize the following system exactly [(1+sT1)(1-sT2)]/(as^2+bs+c) ?

Comment: @user33623 Sorry I don't see the problem you are seeing. T1 = CRa, T2 = CRb, \$\omega_0^2\$ is just a gain fudge and this is dead easy to implement.

Comment: @Andyaka, are you not seeing his filter is non-minimum phase?  The rightmost term in the numerator of his transfer function is a right half-plane zero.  The zeros in your transfer function are both left half-plane zeros.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Ah I see what you mean - no I missed that one. I'll have a rethink

Comment: @AlfredCentauri,@Andy aka is it possible to realize this type of non-minimum phase transfer function? if so can you suggest

Comment: @user33623 the circuits in my answer and Alfred's answer are all realizable as they are shown.

Comment: @Andyaka ..Minimum phase systems are realizable as we know..bt i want to know whether non-minimum phase transfer functions of this type are exactly/approximately realizable?

Comment: @user33623 I'm not knowledgeable enough to give an answer to this question - I can apply a bunch of op-amps to make a transfer function (with a little help from Alfred) as per your question but it's been years since I went to school!!

Comment: @Andyaka...no prob..you can give a try

Comment: @user33623 I can't guess I'm sorry - I barely recognize the term "non-minimum phase transfer function"

Answer (score 1):

> but how to synthesize RHP zero is the difficulty i am facing.

I'm certain there's a more elegant way but this circuit will give a RHP zero:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvlkwm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$\frac{V_o}{V_i} = -(1 - sRC) $$